# ECharts Confidence Band (Line) chart defaulting to 0 with null values

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, google-visualization, echarts

I am converting Google Chart confidence band (line) to Apache Echarts and I have a major issue when using areaStyle on confidence-band stacking in the line charts with null values.

The issue arises only when having null values in the min/max lines. The connectNulls seems to not be affecting the areaStyle, where the actual line is drawn. Also, the option for skipping xAxis values where the yAxis values are nulls is not an option since in some cases, multiple confidence bands sets will be show (as seen in the second screenshot).

[Here is a screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ln4jE.png)

[And here is a screenshot of how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrqZT.png)

Here is a simplified data and options:

```
var dataPoints = [
    {
        "date": "1988",
        "value": null,
        "max": null,
        "min": null
    },
    {
        "date": "1993",
        "value": null,
        "max": null,
        "min": null
    },
    {
        "date": "1994",
        "value": -25.06951746031746,
        "max": -4.489982345190423,
        "min": -45.6490525754445
    },
    {
        "date": "1995",
        "value": null,
        "max": null,
        "min": null
    },
    {
        "date": "1996",
        "value": null,
        "max": null,
        "min": null
    },
    {
        "date": "1997",
        "value": null,
        "max": null,
        "min": null
    },
    {
        "date": "1998",
        "value": -22.481579457241587,
        "max": -13.261933619688394,
        "min": -31.70122529479478
    },
    {
        "date": "1999",
        "value": null,
        "max": null,
        "min": null
    },
    {
        "date": "2001",
        "value": null,
        "max": null,
        "min": null
    },
    {
        "date": "2002",
        "value": -15.762091749175111,
        "max": -7.987435161930629,
        "min": -23.536748336419592
    },
    {
        "date": "2004",
        "value": null,
        "max": null,
        "min": null
    },
    {
        "date": "2005",
        "value": -15.991292690156723,
        "max": -10.553503467629257,
        "min": -21.42908191268419
    },
    {
        "date": "2006",
        "value": -15.571244626678256,
        "max": -10.249573325928019,
        "min": -20.892915927428493
    },
    {
        "date": "2008",
        "value": null,
        "max": null,
        "min": null
    },
    {
        "date": "2009",
        "value": -15.220561608383338,
        "max": -10.272665580901526,
        "min": -20.168457635865153
    },
    {
        "date": "2010",
        "value": -14.663968598988458,
        "max": -9.842327372229358,
        "min": -19.48560982574756
    },
    {
        "date": "2011",
        "value": -12.819286135182983,
        "max": -7.97250885239146,
        "min": -17.666063417974506
    },
    {
        "date": "2012",
        "value": null,
        "max": null,
        "min": null
    },
    {
        "date": "2014",
        "value": null,
        "max": null,
        "min": null
    },
    {
        "date": "2015",
        "value": null,
        "max": null,
        "min": null
    },
    {
        "date": "2016",
        "value": null,
        "max": null,
        "min": null
    },
    {
        "date": "2017",
        "value": -13.945108519331527,
        "max": -9.216373427532616,
        "min": -18.673843611130437
    },
    {
        "date": "2018",
        "value": null,
        "max": null,
        "min": null
    },
    {
        "date": "2019",
        "value": -13.384577319672625,
        "max": -9.017162823138271,
        "min": -17.751991816206978
    }
];

option =
    {
        grid: {
            containLabel: true,
        },
        tooltip: {
            trigger: 'axis',
            backgroundColor: '#38393c',
            textStyle: {
                color: "#FFF",
            },
        },
        legend: {
            show: true,
            top: 'top',
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            boundaryGap: false,
            data: dataPoints.map(function (item) {
                return item.date;
            }),
        },
        yAxis: {
        },
        series: [
        {   //Max Line
            name: 'Max',
            type: 'line',
            data: dataPoints.map(function (item) {
                return item.max;
            }),
            lineStyle: {
                opacity: 1,
            },
            areaStyle: {
                color: 'transparent',
                opacity: 1,
            },
            stack: 'confidence-band',
            stackStrategy: 'all',
            symbol: 'none',
            connectNulls: true,
        },
        {   //Min Line
            name: 'Min',
            type: 'line',
            data: dataPoints.map(function (item) {
                return item.min - item.max;
            }),
            lineStyle: {
                opacity: 1,
            },
            areaStyle: {
                color: 'red',
                opacity: 0.5,
            },
            stack: 'confidence-band',
            stackStrategy: 'all',
            symbol: 'none',
            connectNulls: true,
        },
        {   //Value Line
            name: 'Mean Values',
            type: 'line',
            data: dataPoints.map(function (item) {
                return item.value;
            }),
            itemStyle: {
                color: 'teal',
            },
            showSymbol: false,
            connectNulls: true,
        },
    ],
    };
```

[Here is a link to the echarts with reproducible example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=area-stack&code=G4QwTgBAJiAuIAUD2BLAdrAzhAvBA2gFAQkQDexpVARDLAKbUBcE1AjAJwAcX1ANJSolqoADYBXRizTjRogUNLUAtiAAezCDLkLFrZek3bRgiAF9dJCntZ0prThwDM_UzTGSjs-W6WqN0t6WQiqGgXKmFqbWerRw9uwcHAAsrjYiIBL2ALQATACsAHQADABsHPlsAOzJpcVO1bXBNP6a2cmFyVxJXLlOyZUcxcl9zX5hEO1FpclD-QVV-cnL-ZHBMYpxDJqJFWmxHvbGY8Kt4T7pBmheEVRRVBshdjuOpfubhzcXsWdaQb6nCbGNbRAG2eIvJJVd4hT7nE76dRfBGha7nEEPMFbBKOXgouGTXK5TpcNj5Kopcm5ZJkrhVFG_bJsJyFXKlThOJzsjilHhOFIMibZBqFKrFNhE-YpCnJKpcDGkR40Z4sXYcGHuTKeeFY37HXVA7wKqxYlWsXLFcUapQE_WXJE6y6G26ke6K00Q1UW4q5a3CAlMopVUoWjiNMOLNhRhkOyZVQrcGpOSrcpxlXIcQVowks_JcmpcTkzTj5Di5Y3kD3bL2W1L4rVHf72gJ_HQG7PAu7rKsJb35P2sANkhNhjNsoZk0pVUa62NM4qFfJ5_L1WrBsfkrNtXJsToZ4qk0e8mkcCtKpRm6jet71rJtYfkiXLEOlKe9fKlGMt-es2bkzkFGWXDipm7bbgu3QZmSZY1LkXCzE4Z49js3p4litpNj8sZ2j8zomF2oLpJe3rqre2qTMORLFB-bB1IWhaclwX73guuTTq-S7ARO8yfmBLB5AutHweSpTJlwpSVHmSFEZ65risUA4ZHe_FsB0r78rypbdDwAxMbO34cIU8F9GxTjTkSzj5HpTrZkyhldB-xTcAssoftJsTEeKbCKUOxKHnB7LJmwvTcE4zH8fGHDTiuPDzPyqm8TZ97xq-dSiTSFI1CupTuZsnkSj5DbIvpxVJeiBGYjJ1ZyaphXKa23ybHqmFNXhuVPLJV7iv2ZGNm2zalbhHZGhV7pVb24o3uhRWOlhLY4a1w0uiQbomuNKHitCvX3iylJsAegycmSbHhZMhk7qJVT9GxeZsrRW4qVwhRTk48FclGzLDGZ7XKp1FrBXV5ELSEzX9UNXw_Ref0gYDOTMoUr0DFUV2cFObIFKd2SGZttFwX0zK9FUbAPRR8aRkkwW42UUXynchAALoANyEIQSAAA6wCgSBoLghF6AA5mAKBQCw56KAAxtz8DoAAMiAABG9CiCwsBgJICKrUIsBIEgoic2zotglQqsoPz_P0GALAAOTqCgmBWwiVDyyA4sANaC0g4hoFAADCutIJbEBWwAxK9_JOOLDtG6QDBqLAADKsAAJ6iPQhs2DYkuiAHqrBwAYgXA6jYomtUKn5ve-nGckJgAAWSAAO4q2r9COzH7PW9rbNRzYpekGoACCah21X1fJ2zadB-L8T8wHSc99XEDy573vgEnADiIAGxAABmmSYK30ckHQIAsCfyDoFghSqGzAAUO9e-LnPcxAt8oAwygAJSVovQhgPQsBxBgB5u_egyhCh2GZr_Mwn8NYIiTkPEeP89B9xrhbFA9BMAsCIDYMgpAAD0-CACy6gIAy3QPQI-WgQDKEnlbEhagF5jyThPa2ogKFMIzifM-cBECoAwJga-W976P2fjzN-H9v5iwzv_QBwCICgPAf4KBi8YFtxIOwtA9BE4p0ntImw7MXbvyTiwYmVDUFCHAPQEAOjU6j1_hALOOcg6qxAGgTAbMrEYE4b_Qx4tjGmPUeYIJmB4Bu2tpLNAO9hb0DQOLeg2Rnbex8XoUJLtXaJzADPExQdMiiBSYoTASdlDL2VkHNA3N6AFKEJErRT8ABy3gsEQFVurMEFi8EkEIUQ9AZCKFULQDQuhPS0DVONiwuhmiqlBO4dAXhF8BFCLvg_OJYjX6KKkVQqgsigEgI_tfXp2QFH7OUeY2BVCpm2L0Vs0gfiAkQDMdAoJVibHJzscghxjj_aBytv_KAYy9B3OTiwBc-QgkWKoGk8JU9ubRKgLE-JiS3H_JCWEjJriGD8xyTbOQAKa7FNKdbCpWi8VfLQHU2AjS5DNNaYfXuCJOkQEIQANQbH0rRAyhnWyIdYnmrKsj2yCePSZHCZm8J4fABZV8b4iNWVzcRGyPkOJ2fIxRhRDgqOrmoqhiirn2N_k4n5DBMikohaQOujd44Et1iwPeogD5BNqfQBpTTm5tPpaYemwQzCMyAA)

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure I understand why you can't eliminate `null` points, maybe if you could make an example for the case where that's not feasible, I can think of a solution simpler than the one I proposed below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this possibly qualifies as a bug in echarts - it fails to work with `null`s in stacked data. It boils down to [this if statement](https://github.com/apache/echarts/blob/master/src/chart/line/helper.ts#L124) that results in a replacement of `null` to zero in polygons, shapes that get filled if `areaStyle` is enabled. Still, given the complexity of the code, I don't know whether that replacement was not necessary for some other type of plot.

In the code below I made a patch that filters out NaN values from polygons produced by `LineView.prototype._newPolygon`; I prepended it to your code. It appears to do the job, but this is a very hacky solution. I would recommend considering taking out the `null` values, or even interpolating for the missing data.

```js
const LineView = echarts.ChartView.getClass('line');
const _newPolygon = LineView.prototype._newPolygon;
LineView.prototype._newPolygon = function(points, stackedOnPoints){
    const polygon = _newPolygon.call(this, points, stackedOnPoints);
    if(points && stackedOnPoints){
        const setShape = polygon.setShape;
        polygon.setShape = function(keyOrObj, value){
            const _poly = setShape.call(polygon, keyOrObj, value);
            const points = polygon.shape.points,
                stackedOnPoints = polygon.shape.stackedOnPoints,
                points2 = [], stackedOnPoints2 = [];
            let foundNaN = false;
            for(let i = 0; i < points.length/2; i++){
                if(!isNaN(points[2*i+1]) && !isNaN(stackedOnPoints[2*i+1])){
                    points2.push(points[2*i], points[2*i+1]);
                    stackedOnPoints2.push(stackedOnPoints[2*i], stackedOnPoints[2*i+1]);
                }
                else{
                    foundNaN = true;
                }
            }
            if(foundNaN){
                polygon.shape.points = new Float32Array(points2);
                polygon.shape.stackedOnPoints = new Float32Array(stackedOnPoints2);
            }

            return _poly;
        }
    }
    return polygon;
};

var dom = document.getElementById('chart-container');
var myChart = echarts.init(dom, null, {
    renderer: 'canvas',
    useDirtyRect: false
});
var app = {};

var option;

var dataPoints = [
    {
        "date": "1988",
        "value": null,
        "max": null,
        "min": null
    },
    {
        "date": "1993",
        "value": null,
        "max": null,
        "min": null
    },
    {
        "date": "1994",
        "value": -25.06951746031746,
        "max": -4.489982345190423,
        "min": -45.6490525754445
    },
    {
        "date": "1995",
        "value": null,
        "max": null,
        "min": null
    },
    {
        "date": "1996",
        "value": null,
        "max": null,
        "min": null
    },
    {
        "date": "1997",
        "value": null,
        "max": null,
        "min": null
    },
    {
        "date": "1998",
        "value": -22.481579457241587,
        "max": -13.261933619688394,
        "min": -31.70122529479478
    },
    {
        "date": "1999",
        "value": null,
        "max": null,
        "min": null
    },
    {
        "date": "2001",
        "value": null,
        "max": null,
        "min": null
    },
    {
        "date": "2002",
        "value": -15.762091749175111,
        "max": -7.987435161930629,
        "min": -23.536748336419592
    },
    {
        "date": "2004",
        "value": null,
        "max": null,
        "min": null
    },
    {
        "date": "2005",
        "value": -15.991292690156723,
        "max": -10.553503467629257,
        "min": -21.42908191268419
    },
    {
        "date": "2006",
        "value": -15.571244626678256,
        "max": -10.249573325928019,
        "min": -20.892915927428493
    },
    {
        "date": "2008",
        "value": null,
        "max": null,
        "min": null
    },
    {
        "date": "2009",
        "value": -15.220561608383338,
        "max": -10.272665580901526,
        "min": -20.168457635865153
    },
    {
        "date": "2010",
        "value": -14.663968598988458,
        "max": -9.842327372229358,
        "min": -19.48560982574756
    },
    {
        "date": "2011",
        "value": -12.819286135182983,
        "max": -7.97250885239146,
        "min": -17.666063417974506
    },
    {
        "date": "2012",
        "value": null,
        "max": null,
        "min": null
    },
    {
        "date": "2014",
        "value": null,
        "max": null,
        "min": null
    },
    {
        "date": "2015",
        "value": null,
        "max": null,
        "min": null
    },
    {
        "date": "2016",
        "value": null,
        "max": null,
        "min": null
    },
    {
        "date": "2017",
        "value": -13.945108519331527,
        "max": -9.216373427532616,
        "min": -18.673843611130437
    },
    {
        "date": "2018",
        "value": null,
        "max": null,
        "min": null
    },
    {
        "date": "2019",
        "value": -13.384577319672625,
        "max": -9.017162823138271,
        "min": -17.751991816206978
    }
];

option =
    {
        grid: {
            containLabel: true,
        },
        tooltip: {
            trigger: 'axis',
            backgroundColor: '#38393c',
            textStyle: {
                color: "#FFF",
            },
        },
        legend: {
            show: true,
            top: 'top',
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            boundaryGap: false,
            data: dataPoints.map(function (item) {
                return item.date;
            }),
        },
        yAxis: {
        },
        series: [
            {   //Max Line
                name: 'Max',
                type: 'line',
                data: dataPoints.map(function (item) {
                    return item.max;
                }),
                lineStyle: {
                    opacity: 1,
                },
                areaStyle: {
                    color: 'transparent',
                    opacity: 1,
                },
                stack: 'confidence-band',
                stackStrategy: 'all',
                symbol: 'none',
                connectNulls: true,
            },
            {   //Min Line
                name: 'Min',
                type: 'line',
                data: dataPoints.map(function (item) {
                    return item.min - item.max;
                }),
                lineStyle: {
                    opacity: 1,
                },
                areaStyle: {
                    color: 'red',
                    opacity: 0.5,
                },
                stack: 'confidence-band',
                stackStrategy: 'all',
                symbol: 'none',
                connectNulls: true,
            },
            {   //Value Line
                name: 'Mean Values',
                type: 'line',
                data: dataPoints.map(function (item) {
                    return item.value;
                }),
                itemStyle: {
                    color: 'teal',
                },
                showSymbol: false,
                connectNulls: true,
            },
        ],
    };

if (option && typeof option === 'object') {
    myChart.setOption(option);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', myChart.resize);
```

```css
#chart-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://fastly.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const originalData = [
  { date: 'Mon', value: 820 },
  { date: 'Tue', value: 932 },
  { date: 'Wed', value: 0 },
  { date: 'Thu', value: 934 },
  { date: 'Fri', value: 1290 },
  { date: 'Sat', value: 1330 },
  { date: 'Sun', value: 1320 }
];

const processedData = originalData.map(item => ({
  name: item.date, 
  value: item.value === 0 ? null : item.value
}));

const chartOption = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
    // ... xAxis configurations
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
 
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: processedData,
      type: 'line',
      connectNulls: true, // this is important if you want to connect the lines
     
    }
  ],
};
```

Comment: The main issue was that Google charts (the previous option) did work well without connecting the nulls. Also, connecting the nulls will draw the background overlay but that is portraying wrong data as it looks as there ware points along the X axis.
Either way, we ended up staying with Google Charts for this type of chart. I will revisit it another time with a newer version.