# chartjs stacked line with spanGaps not spanning correctly

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to plot a line chart as stacked, and because there is some missing data - I figured spanGaps would be a good option - but it looks like this works if it's the "top" line, but if the gaps exist (i.e. `data: [20, undefined, 21, 22, 25, 26, 24, 28, 30, 25, 22],`) below that then it causes a problem with the stacking on top.

[image]

Is this a bug, or is there a way around this (short of trying to create interim dummy values based on the known values, etc)?

```js
var config_working = {
  type: 'line',

  data: {
    labels: ['01 May 2023', '02 May 2023', '03 May 2023', '04 May 2023', '05 May 2023', '06 May 2023', '07 May 2023', '08 May 2023', '09 May 2023', '10 May 2023'],

    datasets: [{
      label: 'Full History',
      borderColor: '#3182BD',
      backgroundColor: '#3182BD',
      data: [20, 15, 21, 22, 25, 26, 24, 28, 30, 25, 22],
      // Count is 11
      fill: true

    },{
      label: 'Gappy data',
      borderColor: '#2c6145',
      backgroundColor: '#2c6145',
      data: [15, 14, 12, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 12, 10, 14, 15],
      // Count is 11
      fill: true

    }]
  },

  options: {
    type: 'line',
    spanGaps: true,
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      y: {
        stacked: true
      }
    }
  }
};

var config_problem = {
  type: 'line',

  data: {
    labels: ['01 May 2023', '02 May 2023', '03 May 2023', '04 May 2023', '05 May 2023', '06 May 2023', '07 May 2023', '08 May 2023', '09 May 2023', '10 May 2023'],

    datasets: [{
      label: 'History with one gap',
      borderColor: '#3182BD',
      backgroundColor: '#3182BD',
      data: [20, undefined, 21, 22, 25, 26, 24, 28, 30, 25, 22],
      // Count is 11
      fill: true

    },{
      label: 'Gappy data',
      borderColor: '#2c6145',
      backgroundColor: '#2c6145',
      data: [15, 14, 12, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 12, 10, 14, 15],
      // Count is 11
      fill: true

    }]
  },

  options: {
    type: 'line',
    spanGaps: true,
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      y: {
        stacked: true
      }
    }
  }
};

window.onload = function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('cvs-working').getContext('2d');
  window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config_working);
  
  var ctx = document.getElementById('cvs-problem').getContext('2d');
  window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config_problem);
};
```

```css
h1 {
border-top:solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<script type='text/JavaScript' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js'></script>


  <h1>
  Working(?)...
  </h1>
<div style='height:300px'>
  <canvas id='cvs-working'></canvas>
</div>

<h1>
Problem...
</h1>
<div style='height:300px'>
  <canvas id='cvs-problem'></canvas>
</div>
```

(Note, tbh, i'm not sure the "Working?..." one is working either - as it doesn't seem to be spanning the gap for the blue series)

A jsfiddle is also available to play with...https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/s07fkh69/65/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I find that the first chart works as
expected, the values where the second line is, are
exactly those they should be: `[35, 29, 33,----,40,40,39,37]`.
Maybe it's easier to see if you add `beginAtZero: true`
to your y axis (see example below).

As for the not-working version, this seems to be the default
behavior, I've seen it in other libraries, (e.g., echarts,
see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75598482/echarts-confidence-band-line-chart-defaulting-to-0-with-null-values)).
If I think more about it, I come to the conclusion
that there is a reason for it, and I wouldn't call it
a bug anymore:

- with `spanGaps` all we do is *ignore* a non-numeric value, drawing a segment over a gap,
  as it were *missing*.
- what we are expecting is that non-numeric value to
  be *replaced* by a new value that may be *computed* through
  interpolation. That's more than `spanGaps` is supposed to
  do.

Still, the interpolation behavior is possible (and
not extremely complicated) to implement in the chartjs code.

It can also be implemented to a certain extent in userland.
Here's an extension to the [`LineController`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/api/#linecontroller)
that I called `LineControllerWithGapInterpolation`, with
the `id` `line_with_gap_interpolation` (to be used as the
type of the chart or dataset).

It has some limitations: it only works with lines (no
spline interpolation, `tension` option is ignored), and it
**needs that all the x values are defined** (so for that I
added the 11th day to your example).

```js
//import {Chart, registerables, Legend, LineController} from "./chart.js";
//Chart.register(...registerables);

// for umd script: (remove if import above is used)
const LineController = Chart.LineController;

class LineControllerWithGapInterpolation extends LineController{
    static id = 'line_with_gap_interpolation';

    initialize(){
        super.initialize();
        this.options.tension = 0;
    }

    parse(start, count){
        const { _cachedMeta: meta } = this;
        const { _stacked  } = meta;
        super.parse(start, count);
        if(_stacked) {
            const parsed = meta._parsed;
            let lastX = null, lastY = null, allOK = true, changed = false;
            const parsedWithInterp = parsed.map(
                function(o, i){
                    if(!allOK){
                        return o;
                    }
                    const o2 = {x:o.x, y: o.y};
                    if(Number.isFinite(o.y)){
                        lastX = o.x;
                        lastY = o.y;
                        if(!Number.isFinite(lastX)){
                            allOK = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        let nextX = null, nextY = null;
                        for(let j = i + 1; j < parsed.length; j++){
                            if(Number.isFinite(parsed[j].y)){
                                nextX = parsed[j].x;
                                nextY = parsed[j].y;
                                if(!Number.isFinite(nextX)){
                                    allOK = false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        //interpolation
                        o2.y = (nextY - lastY) / (nextX - lastX) * (o.x - lastX) + lastY;
                        changed = true;
                    }
                    return o2;
                }
            );
            if(allOK){
                if(changed){
                    const save_parsed = parsed.map(o => o);
                    this._data = parsedWithInterp.map(({y}) => y);
                    super.parse(start, count);
                    this._cachedMeta._parsed.forEach((o, i) => {o.y = save_parsed[i].y});
                }
            }
            else{
                console.warn('x data missing, could not interpolate'+
                    (((meta.index || meta.index === 0) && ' dataset '+meta.index) ?? ''))
            }
        }
    }
}

Chart.register(LineControllerWithGapInterpolation);

var config_working = {
    type: 'line',

    data: {
        labels: ['01 May 2023', '02 May 2023', '03 May 2023', '04 May 2023', '05 May 2023', '06 May 2023', '07 May 2023', '08 May 2023', '09 May 2023', '10 May 2023', '11 May 2023'],

        datasets: [{
            label: 'Full History',
            borderColor: '#3182BD',
            backgroundColor: '#3182BD',
            data: [20, 20.5, 21, 22, 25, 26, 24, 28, 30, 25, 22],
            // Count is 11
            fill: true
        // },{
        //     label: 'Another Full History',
        //     borderColor: '#BD8231',
        //     backgroundColor: '#BD8231',
        //     data: [20, 12, 21, 22, 25, 25.5, 24, 28, 30, 26, 22],
        //     // Count is 11
        //     fill: true
        },{
            label: 'Gappy data',
            borderColor: '#2c6145',
            backgroundColor: '#2c6145',
            data: [15, 14, 12, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 12, 10, 14, 15],
            //should be: [35, 29, 33,----,40,40,39,37]
            // Count is 11
            fill: true,
        }]
    },

    options: {
        type: 'line',
        spanGaps: true,
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        pointRadius: 0,
        scales: {
            y: {
                stacked: true,
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
};

var config_problem = {
    type: 'line_with_gap_interpolation',

    data: {
        labels: ['01 May 2023', '02 May 2023', '03 May 2023', '04 May 2023', '05 May 2023', '06 May 2023', '07 May 2023', '08 May 2023', '09 May 2023', '10 May 2023', '11 May 2023'],

        datasets: [{
            label: 'With one gap',
            borderColor: '#3182BD',
            backgroundColor: '#3182BD',
            data: [20, undefined, 21, 22, 25, 26, 24, 28, 30, 25, 22],
            fill: true
        // },{
        //     label: 'With two gaps',
        //     borderColor: '#BD8231',
        //     backgroundColor: '#BD8231',
        //     data: [20, 12, 21, 22, 25, undefined, 24, 28, 30, undefined, 22],
        //     fill: true
        },{
            label: 'Gappy data',
            borderColor: '#2c6145',
            backgroundColor: '#2c6145',
            data: [15, 14, 12, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 12, 10, 14, 15],
            fill: true
        }]
    },

    options: {
        type: 'line',
        spanGaps: true,
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        pointRadius: 0,
        scales: {
            y: {
                stacked: true,
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
};

window.onload = function() {
     var ctx = document.getElementById('cvs-working').getContext('2d');
     window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config_working);

    var ctx = document.getElementById('cvs-problem').getContext('2d');
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config_problem);
};
```

```html
<div style="width:46vw; height: 300px; display: inline-block">
    <canvas id="cvs-working"></canvas>
</div>
<div style="width:46vw; height: 300px; display: inline-block">
    <canvas id="cvs-problem"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.3.0/chart.umd.js" integrity="sha512-CMF3tQtjOoOJoOKlsS7/2loJlkyctwzSoDK/S40iAB+MqWSaf50uObGQSk5Ny/gfRhRCjNLvoxuCvdnERU4WGg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Excellent response kikon - thanks for everything.